# top.location.href doesn't work in IE 8

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

`top.location.href` doesn't work in IE8 from my facebook application when i redirect people to another URL.

Anyone have any other solution to redirect a user to another URL (It's need to redirect the URL outside the iframe, in this case the `apps.facebook.com/application` URL and not my domain URL)

Anyone have any solution?

Comment: Do you get a yellow triangle in the corner?

Comment: It's working now with @VMAtm 's solution :-)

Comment: Very strange. Perhaps they have hijacked "top"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `window.top.location = "NEW_URL"` for the IE. Or, if your code is run from `iframe`, `parent.location = "NEW_URL"`

Comment: I found out, that it didn't worked with parent.location on IE :s

Answer (score 1):

Fairly old post, but I'd thought I'd share the solution that worked for me:

I found that when in an iFrame (within a Facebook Tab), I had to use

parent.location.**href** = "NEW URL";

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and you would not believe what the error was... i added a line in de dsk of facebook (facebook.php)! I downloaded the latest version, but i think it wasn't updated since Auth2.0

**Wrong:**

```
    protected static $DROP_QUERY_PARAMS = array(
       'code',
       'state',
      'signed_request',
    );
```

**Right:**

```
    protected static $DROP_QUERY_PARAMS = array(
       'code',
       'state',
       'signed_request',
   'base_domain',
    );
```

The redirect was only not working in IE, after this modification it worked..

Answer (score 0):

`top.location.href= "URL"` works for me, just make sure that the URL is absolute.