# Reload loops in infinity in safari and internet explorer

Tags: php, javascript

I have this code which helps me to reload a page.
The issue is, it works with Chrome and Firefox but not with Safari, it loops continually.

Can you help me why is this happening?

This is the code:

```
top.location.href=\'http://www.facebook.com/pages/Penelope-NS/327068327378161?sk=app_338788849530374\';
```

Can i do this otherwise?

Thanks

I found this code: Where am i supposed to insert it?

```
headers 'Content-Type' => "text/html;charset=utf-8",
  'Last-Modified' => Time.now.httpdate,
  'P3P' => 'CP="CAO PSA OUR"',
  'X-UA-Compatible' => 'IE=edge'
```

Comment: if its done after loading, then it should loop. Where are you doing it?

Comment: Yes, it's done after loading, but it loops to infinity, it should just loop once, just like mozilla and chrome..

Comment: Regarding code you found — these are headers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Also, could you provide your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `window.top.location = "NEW_URL"` for the IE. Or, if your code is run from iframe, `parent.location = "NEW_URL"`

[Maybe same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712528/top-location-href-doesnt-work-in-ie-8)

**Update:**

To address the same page where the script itself resides:
`self.location.href = newURL;`

To address another page in a frameset:
`window.top.frameName.location.href = newURL;`

or (hypercorrect):

`window.top.frames['frameName'].location.href = newURL;`

Comment: My main problem is safari here... Ie, well, i don't care if things don't work there, but safari is essential!

Answer (score 0):

`top.location.href` depends on browser, and top.location popup allowance. most browsers should allow this, but older mac browsers tend to not allow this.

Update Safari to the latest version and it should work. For older safari browsers, it doesn't support `top.location` script execution.

Comment: I do have safari 5.1.5 , the latest version is 5.1.7, do you think it's a big difference for it now to work?

Comment: Ok that should be fine, check that JS and popups are allowed in your safari preferences. hit `Ctrl+,` and go to `Security`, Safari blocks pop-up windows by default.

Comment: Can you please see my updated question?
Maybe i can fix it with that? Because this doesn't look like popup aren't allowed..

Comment: Nah that shouldn't affect a pop-up, that's all to do with header declarations for browsers when downloading certain data. Pop-ups are your main concern. RE: my last post, were your Safari settings set to `On`? Pop-up-block checkbox should be unchecked for your code to work in Safari 5.1.5.

Comment: Yeah, but that header solved my IE problem, and i don't know why in some safari's that code works in some others not..

Comment: interesting. as said before, earlier Mac browsers (eg. early Safari versions) didn't allow `top.location` to execute.